# error when making bake de normal map in blender 3.0

Tags: texture-baking

I'm having trouble making the bake of the normal map of an object, as you can see has a stripe, well in the division in the seam of the uv map, as shown in the image
[image]

i'm making the scales of a snake.
I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: why do you have an invert node after you image texture node?

Comment: I have an invert node, because as you can see the normal map texture is green, not blue. I searched the Internet for a solution for this and found the solution with the invert node

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake, I was saving the texture of normal map like jpg, so I saved in PNG format and it worked out